# Return the index of max value from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to loop over the parameter vector and find which is the biggest index. If the biggest index exists in multiple places it is going to return the highest index value.

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
static int maxIndex(int vector[]) {
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < vector.length; i++) {

        if (vector[i] >= vector[maxIndex]) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return maxIndex;
}
```

Comment: The answer is obvious - the biggest index is the latest one. You're actually trying to find index of maximum value in the array.

Comment: What makes you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: The code appears to be right. What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: How am i even suppost to input the numbers?

Comment: That's totally different from your original question.

Comment: Maybe it is, however i still dont know how i do it.

Comment: well you should ask your real question, so what are you confuse about inserrt number to array?

Comment: `int[] v = { 1, 4, 2, 4, 1 }; assert maxIndex(v) == 3;` By the way best place the brackets after the type: `int[] a` instead of the C-style `int a[]`.

Comment: I feel like you guys are talking another language, keep in mind i'm a complete noob. I have been programming for less than 2 months. My question is how i am suppost to write the code so it returns the biggest index, if it exists in multiple places it is going to return the highest index value. By that i mean i also want to know where i am suppost to write the numbers. in main?

Comment: `main` is a good place to start

Comment: @OliverBäckström yes from the `main`. `maxIndex` is a method, its goal is to be called to execute something. The easiest way to call your method right now, is from the `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code.

```
static int maxIndex(int[] vector) {

    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {

        maxIndex = vector[i] > vector[maxIndex] ? i : maxIndex;
    }

    return maxIndex;
}
```

Call as follow

```
int[] arr = [2,3,5,1];
System.out.println( maxIndex(arr));
```

This will return **2** the index of max value **5**

Comment: You're missing a few characters in your example call (semicolons and parentheses around the println statement, as well as qualifier for the println)

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke : Ohh, This is the Groovy syntax, will correct that, Thanks

Comment: @NitinDhomse Also curly brackets for arrays. The pitfalls of being a multi language developer xD

Answer (score 0):

Every element of the array have unique index value, which start from 0 for the first element and so on. So the array cannot have multiple index. What I understand from your problem statement is that you want to return the index value of largest number in the array and if the number exists more than once you want to return the last index of that number.
If this is your problem that code help you

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    static int maxIndex(int vector[]) {
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < vector.length; i++) {

        if (vector[i] >= vector[maxIndex]) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return maxIndex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={4,3,1,2,4,6,7,2,7,6}; 
        System.out.println(maxIndex(a));
    }
}
```

Your function is working properly I just passed an array to that funtion.

**OR**

If you want to take a input from user just replace the below code with the main method of the solution class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int b=scan.nextInt();
    int a[]= new int[b]; 
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
        a[i]=scan.nextInt();
    }
    scan.close();
    System.out.println(maxIndex(a));
}
```

As a beginner in programming just try to make a approach don't focus on user input.
Hopefully that help